# tickInterval Inside an interval

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Is it possible to set sub tick intervals? I need to have a tick with a difference of 50 in the first interval only of the Y-axis which has a tick with a difference of 250.

If the max value for Y-axis is 1500 then Y-axis will have the following intervals:
`0, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250, 1500`.

In the 0 - 250 range I would like `0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250`

So the intervals on Y-axis should look like:
`0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250, 1500`.

```
function loadColumnBarChart(Hired, Scrned, AllTimPreQulfd, Qualfid, AllTimSAD, SAD, SMD, Aprvd, pndin) {
    $('#chartMain').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: Data Flow'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Hired',
                'Screened',
                'Pre-Qualified',
                'Submitted All Docs',
                'Submittted Missing Docs',
                'Approved',
                'Pending'
            ],
            crosshair: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            tickInterval: 250,
         // tickPixelInterval: 50,
            title: {
                text: 'Employees'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} </b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },    
        series: [{
            name: 'Current Status',
                data: [Hired, Scrned, Qualfid, SAD, SMD, Aprvd, pndin]
            }, {
                name: 'Total Amount',
                data: [Hired, Scrned, AllTimPreQulfd, AllTimSAD, SMD, Aprvd, pndin]

        }]
    });
}
```

Comment: I think you'll have to explain what you want a little more clearly (an illustration would help). However, you can do pretty much anything you want with your tick positioning by using the **tickPositions** property, or the **tickPositioner** function: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositions | http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: @jibriggs updated the question with more illustration.

Comment: So, the answer then is yes, but you have to do the math yourself, using one of the two methods mentioned in my previous comment. You can pre-process, and return an array of y values to the **tickPositions** at which to draw a tickmark, or you can supply the function to calculate them as a callback to the **tickPositioner** function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a crude example, based on the docs, that you can cleanup as needed:

**Code:**

```
yAxis: {
  min: 0,
  max: 1500,
  tickPositioner: function() {
    var positions = [],
      tick = 0,
      increment1 = 50,
      increment2 = 250;
    for (tick; tick < 250; tick += increment1) {
      positions.push(tick);
    }
    for (tick; tick - increment2 < this.max; tick += increment2) {
      positions.push(tick);
    }
    return positions;
  }
}
```

**Fiddle**:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/9dv97qv1/

**Reference**:

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPositioner